# How to get field structure for a custom content type?

Tags: 8, hooks

I have created a custom content type (mytest) via the Drupal 8 UI.

The content type contains a list field which has the following key|values:

```
gp|GP
device|Device
```

I have tried the following code to retrieve field, but it not there.

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'mytest');
```

Does any one know how to retrieve a List field structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say sorry, I made a mistake in my other part of code.

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'mytest');
```

is correct, it returns all fields belongs to "mytest"

Comment: Nice. Accept your answer if it solved the issue, as a bonus that  seems like a handy one-liner. Thanks.